# Reference in constructor to this (java)

Tags: java, algorithm

[image: This are all possible ways to insert a W into 5x3]
I´m trying to implement a way to find all possible solutions to Pentominos of W, L and I with the help of DLX-Algorithm, or Algorithm-X of Knuth in a 5 x n rectangle.

My approach is to find all ways to insert a W into a 5 x 3 rectangle. I want to implement this first and then the full program.

So this is tons of stuff to read and to understand and I understood somehow how it works but I encountered a problem when looking at this part of the code given by my prof.

```
class Node         // represents 1 element or header
{
  Node C;            // reference to column-header
  Node L,R,U,D;      // left, right, up, down

  Node()
  {
    C=L=R=U=D=this; // supports circular lists
  }
}
```

My question: How does the reference to C=...=this work? I know the difference between instance and local variables but I don't know how to understand the reference to "this" in the constructor. What does it do?

Comment: What do you mean by "the reference to this from D"? It's just an assignment: `C = this; L = this; R = this; U = this; D = this;`. It just means the initial values of the variables are references to the object that "owns" those variables.

Comment: Your question is too broad (because of the last part), and the code does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instruction
    C=L=R=U=D=this;

`this`represents the instance of the Node class that is being processed at runtime (dynamically): so it simply means that all your other Node variable will receieve reference to the current instance of Node that was being constructed.

Comment: still dont understand the reference. Why would i make this reference?